# A compatibility problem between the fontspec package and asymptote

Tags: fontspec, incompatibility, asymptote

Has anyone run across a compatibility issue between the `fontspec` package and `asymptote`?

In the MWE below, commenting out the `\usepackage{fontspec}` allows for proper compilation and embedding of the 3D asymptote manipulative.

Without commenting out the fontspec package, I receive errors like

```
"Latex Error: ./untitled-1.tex:1 LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

 Latex Error: ./untitled-1.tex:9 Undefined control sequence."
```

and while the manipulative is embedded in the output, there's the word `everypage` embedded as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[ItalicFont={Calibri Italic}]{Cambria}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\section{Basic Definitions}
We start with the real numbers 
\begin{center}
\begin{asy} 
    import solids;
    import three;
    import graph3;
    size(14cm,0);
    currentlight=Viewport;
    currentprojection=perspective(4,-4,3);
    material Gray=material(heavygray+opacity(0.75),emissivepen=heavygray,ambientpen=heavygray);
    material Blue=material(blue+opacity(0.75),emissivepen=blue);
    surface y=shift((-.5,0,0))*unitplane;
    draw(scale3(6)*y,Gray);
    draw((0,3,2)--(2,3,0),linewidth(2));
    surface r=shift((0,3,1))*unitsphere;
    draw(surface(r),Blue,render(merge=true));
\end{asy}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This appears to be a problem with XeLaTeX+asymptote; I get the same error without the fontspec package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Will, do you have any idea what the issue is between XeLaTeX and the asymptote package?  Will it occur with LUaLaTeX?